# #JavaScript: switch input in a function after lowercase'd input

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, lowercase, arrow-functions

I'm trying to make a switch work in a function after i lowercased the input.

this is my code:

```
let optie;
const getUserChoise = (userInput) => 
{
 return userInput = userInput.toLowercase;

 switch(userInput){
    case 'rock': return userInput
      break;
      case 'paper': return userInput
      break; 
      case 'scissors': return userInput
      break;
      default :
      console.log(userInput + ' is not an option. Make sure to use: rock, paper or scissors');
  } 

}

getUserChoise('rockwer');
```

for some reason after the lower casing the switch won't read the input.
i've tried to remove the `return` but then it returns `undefined`

I just started learning javascript and am enjoying it. 
all support is welcome.

edit: thank you guys for the quik responds!
Made it very clear for me.

Comment: Missing parentheses: `userInput.toLowercase()`. Without them you are not *calling* the function, but getting the function itself (which is an object). Try to work with the console, and inspect what values variables have. It can help pinpoint such problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just a couple small problems with the code:

1. Anything after a `return` statement is unreachable so with your original `return userInput = userInput.toLowercase` the switch statement afterwards would not run.
2. The `String.prototype.toLowerCase` method is spelled `toLowerCase` not `toLowercase`.
3. You must call the method; e.g., `toLowerCase()`.

Here's the fixed version:

```
const getUserChoise = (userInput) => {
 userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

 switch(userInput){
    case 'rock': return userInput
      break;
      case 'paper': return userInput
      break; 
      case 'scissors': return userInput
      break;
      default :
      console.log(userInput + ' is not an option. Make sure to use: rock, paper or scissors');
  } 

}
```

Comment: Thank you Scott :)

Answer (score 0):

variable userInput has became function definition because of missing parentheses `userInput.toLowercase()`. Because of that code is going into default which is returning `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

A function will stop execution after a return statement. Therefor, instead of assigning `userInput`, you can put `userInput.toLowerCase()` inside of the parentheses like so:

```
let optie;
const getUserChoise = (userInput) => 
{
 switch(userInput.toLowerCase()){
    case 'rock': return userInput
      break;
      case 'paper': return userInput
      break; 
      case 'scissors': return userInput
      break;
      default :
      console.log(userInput + ' is not an option. Make sure to use: rock, paper or scissors');
  } 

}

getUserChoise('rockwer');
```

Hope this works :)
EDIT: In Javascript, it's considered a bad practice to mutate function parameters, which some of these answers do.

Comment: Thank you fifn2 this works for sure,  i'm very new to javascript. Could you explain me what the mutation of function parameters is.

Comment: They mean when you reassigned `userInput` to `userInput.toLowerCase()` with `userInput = userInput.toLowerCase()`. IMO, it's also bad practice to use switch statements; but it's OK since you're new. :)

Comment: There's an article about it [here](https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/avoid-state-mutation/)